# test class for trigger on task

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test

i was new to salesforce.Got stuck while writing test classes

I had written a trigger for getting rollup summary like values(like total number of tasks related to a lead with few conditions)

```
trigger ActivityCountTest on Task (after insert) {

  for(Task task:Trigger.New){

     System.debug(task.CreatedById);
    User user=[SELECT DR_rep__c from USER where id=:task.CreatedById];
     system.debug('user was '+user);
     if((user.DR_rep__c == true) && (task.Subject.contains('Message Sent')||task.Subject.contains('Call')))
     {
         Lead lead=[SELECT Activity_Count__c   from Lead where id=:task.WhoId];
         lead.Activity_Count__c=lead.Activity_Count__c+1;
         update lead;
     }

  }

}
```

But not able to write proper test class for this trigger.The test class i have written is only 66% code coverage..

```
@isTest
public class ActivityCountTest_Test
{
      public static testmethod void testinsert()
      {

 Task task= new task();
task.Subject='Message Sent';
task.status='Completed';
task.Whoid='00Q17000005P3KS';
insert task;

Task task1= new task();
task1.Subject='Call';
task1.status='Completed';
task1.Whoid='00Q17000005P3KS';
insert task1;

Task task2= new task();
task2.Subject='Message Sent';
task2.status='Completed';
task2.Whoid='00Q17000005P1ae';
insert task2;


        }

}
```

I was confused weather i can give hardcode id's or not, any changes in test class are highly appreciable.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I will not add hardcode ids to your test. That is one of the bad practices when writing test classes.Also a good idea will be to use your Developer Console and run the test from there. After that you can view the lines of code that are not been tested. That may help you to target those parts that are not been taken on your test. You could also use a for loop to insert multiple records rather than going through three independent DML operations. Something like:

```
List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();

User user=[SELECT DR_rep__c from USER where id=:task.CreatedById Limit 1];
Id userId = user.Id; 

for(Integer i=0; i<3; i++)
{ 
  taskList.add(new Task(
      Subject='Message Sent',
      status='Completed', 
      WhoId= userId); 

     if(!taskList.isEmpty() && taskList.size()>0)
   {
     insert taskList; 
   }
}
```

I haven't tested but that can help you to reduce DML operations.
You need to also run test on the Lead part. You are updating a lead but there is not leads on your test code.